# How to aggregate data from multiple Google sheets with a tag

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange

I am importing data (using `IMPORTRANGE`) from 3 different sheets to 3 different tabs of a google sheet.

Then I am aggregating those three sheets into one and also filter them using a query.

Ex:

```
=query({BUOne!A1:Y200;BUTwo!A1:Y200;BUThree!A1:Y200},
"Select * where Col1 is not null AND Col14 = 'Bench' order by Col2 ASC")
```

This gives me the data I want from all 3 sheets without a problem.

But I want to know from which sheet each data row came from.
In this case to which BU(BU_One,BU_Two,BU_Three) each record belongs to.

Is there a way to put a tag or a different column when aggregating sheets so I can know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- try like this:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
   BUOne!A1:Y200,   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("×BU_One",   200), "×")); 
   BUTwo!A1:Y200,   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("×BU_Two",   200), "×")); 
   BUThree!A1:Y200, TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("×BU_Three", 200), "×"))},
   "where Col1 is not null 
      and Col14 = 'Bench' 
    order by Col2"))
  ```

Comment: This works perfect except that the new column gets a header as BU_One. Which i can work with at the moment.
Could you please explain how it does the trick? So i can apply the same working in different scenarios. :)

Comment: try perhaps like this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 BUOne!A1:Y200,   {"From"; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("×BU_One",   199), "×"))}; 
 BUTwo!A1:Y200,   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("×BU_Two",   200), "×")); 
 BUThree!A1:Y200, TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("×BU_Three", 200), "×"))},
 "where Col1 is not null 
    and Col14 = 'Bench' 
  order by Col2"))`